# convert series to fix value pine script

Tags: series, pine-script

How I can get a special value in series to Fix value

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

float lastclose = close[1] 
// I want get close last bar (11.00 am 9/5/2021) = 1.21632(EURUSD) , I don't want lastclose is series

plot(lastclose)

// I want this plot
plot(1.21632)
```

You can see in my picture , Red line is that I want.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/DK0Fsdpj/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ4pd.png)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the plot.

```
plot(close, color=color.red, linewidth=4, show_last=1, trackprice=true)
```

This hides the plot and uses a horizontal dotted line to track the level. You could subsitute `close[1]` or similar if you wanted an older close price. If you don't want a dotted line, use `line.new()` and the other line functions to manage and update a line drawing, with extend set to both.

Comment: Thank you, this is also what I need.
But do you know have any way I get close[1] to fix float ?